# Design css class names: Content based vs Function based

Tags: html, css

Currently i'm developing a web-app with jquery and i need to use a lot of css for the first time in my career.

I have a basic design question. What is the usual way for doing with css. Following two easy examples that should face the problem pretty well (just pseudo code):

**Content based:**

html:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a my-panel>
    <div class="ui-block-a my-image>
        <img src="someImage width="10"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b my-text>
        <p>some Text<p>
    </div>
<div>
```

css:

```
.my-panel { /* do stuff e.g alignment, width, ... */ }
.my-panel .my-image { /* do stuff e.g. set flex box, flex align-items, justify-content ... */ }
.my-panel .my-text { /* do stuff e.g. set flex box, flex align-items, justify-content ... */ }
```

**Function based:**

html:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a w-100>
    <div class="ui-block-a align center left>
        <img src="someImage width="10"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b align bottom right>
        <p>some Text<p>
    </div>
<div>
```

css:

```
.w-100 { width: 100% }
.align { /* do basic align stuff e.g. set flex box */ }
.align.top { /* do top alignment e.g. set flex align-items to top */}
.align.bottom { /* do bottom alignment e.g. set align-items to bottom */}
.align.left { /* do left alignment e.g. set flex justify-content to left */}
...
```

I've read that you should try to seperate the basic html from your design in css. I've got the feeling, that the content based version should be the right way to go, because there is no need to know how the css is implemented.

But on the other there are so many doubled defined styles in the content based version. Even if two panels do exactly the same thing, you have to write redundant code for every single part of it. Let's imagine you want to change just one thing, you have to change it in every class again and again.

Thanks for your input and your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. You can use both at the same time.

For example, I have a separate file that contains a lot of **Function based** styles.

I mostly use **Content based**, because I don't like when my html file contains a lot of classes. But sometimes it's very useful to use **Function Based** when you just want to give some div `margin-bottom: 10px`. Instead of writing another css to that div, you can simply add `m-b-10` class to that div. Sorry for English(

Comment: I think mixing is a bad idea. With that you have design in two different placed, html and css. 
Fully functional means, you have your design in your css, and the class names say what they do. So there is no need to watch in the css.
On the other side, fully content based means, you don't have to look in the html, because only the css gives all you need.

Comment: Yes, it's true. But I tried to write some site with fully functional it was very hard for me. So I prefer Content based. But I as I said I use my file. It makes my work much easier (just my experience).

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, maybe some other answers will follow. In the end i will sum up all of this^^